# Alternative way to say "there are a number of limitations to our analysis"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I am looking for an appropriate way to say "there are a number of limitations to our analysis", which does not sound so demeaning to the work we have carried out.

I am new to this site so apologies if I haven't gone about this the correct way.

Comment: Where will be this published and what exactly do you mean by demeaning? What do you try to avoid? "Limitation" is very commonly used when describing studies. "Within the limitation of this systematic review, there is insufficient evidence.." https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27377109

Comment: Thanks @Jan. This isn't being published but is going to a client of ours. To be honest I am happy with the term limitations, it is more the "there are a number of", which to my ears sounds quite bad.

Comment: Words like *inevitably* can convey that the limitations are due to the nature of the exercise and not the way you have gone about it.

Comment: @Minty that is a really good point and exactly the kind of sentence I was trying to convey.

Comment: I don't think ***limitations*** has significant "belittling, derogatory" implications in your context (it's certainly less so than, say, ***deficiencies***). But you might consider using ***caveats*** instead.

Comment: ..."this analysis only goes so far."

Comment: 'We certainly don't claim to have all the answers.'

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is fine as it stands. You could say *There are limitations to our analysis* leaving out the *Number of* description. It would mean much the same.

Telling the audience that you know of the limitations will be taken as you're being serious about the analysis, not demeaning. You would need to follow this by listing or *enumerating* the limitations.